# Python bug: null byte in input prompt

Tags: python, input, prompt, readline, nul

I've found that

```
input('some\x00 text')
```

will prompt for `some` instead of `some text`.

From sources, I've figured out that this function uses C function `PyOS_Readline`, which ignores everything in prompt after NULL byte.

From `PyOS_StdioReadline(FILE *sys_stdin, FILE *sys_stdout, const char *prompt)`:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s", prompt);
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1989
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Parser/myreadline.c#L251

Is this a bug or there is a reason for that?

Issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue30431

Comment: Most like it is a bug.

Comment: since , you can not expect any chars (data) after a NULL byte in almost all use cases , it does not seems to have a bug , also considering that why anyone wants to read after knowing that the NULL character has been reached ! might be a waste of computation for almost all use cases except some like this , correct me if I m wrong ?

Comment: As far as I know in Python NULL byte is not terminating, that is why input is supposed to print whole string

Comment: For example `print('some\0 text')` will print `some text`

Comment: @Костя Чолак, you miss torek's point. It isn't a terminating character in Python, but Python is calling `readline()` and `readline()` is written in C, not in Python, so the C rule applies. Python passes the entire string `"some\x00 text"` to `readline()`, and then `readline()` truncates it.

Comment: Yes, I see. I have no troubles with understanding what goes on. But I'm not sure if it is ok to be so.

Comment: Created issue:
http://bugs.python.org/issue30431

Comment: @torek re-code `readline`? Why could Python not `print` the prompt and call `readline` with the empty string?

Comment: @timgeb: The OS-supplied `readline` must know the prompt so that `readline` can re-print it whenever `readline` wants to (which is frequently). The other option for the prompt itself is for Python to strip out NULs and pass whatever remains to `readline`, but it's not at all clear to me that this is an *improvement*.

Comment: @torek thanks for the explanation, I was not aware of the fact that `readline` could make use of the prompt multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The function signature pretty much requires a *NUL* terminated C-string, `PyOS_StdioReadline(FILE *sys_stdin, FILE *sys_stdout, const char *prompt)`, so there isn't much than can be done about this without changing the API and breaking interoperability with GNU readline.